# PowerApps Onstart navigation

Tags: sharepoint-online, navigation, powerapps-forms, properties, if-condition

I have a PowerApps customized SharePoint list form, and I'm trying to get it to open to different screens based on a Status text field.  I have the main screen "Home Screen", and an approval screen "Project Manager Approval Screen", and when the Status field = "In Progress" (gets updated by a flow), and the email recipient clicks on the "Link to Item", I need them automatically navigated to the Project Manager Approval Screen.  I enabled the OnStart navigation feature in the settings, so I don't have an error.  In the App's OnStart property I have - If(DataCardValue29.Text = "In Progress", Navigate(Project_Director_Approval_Screen))

What am I missing here?  Clicking the Link to Item, just opens the main screen.

Thank you.

Comment: Instead of using value from data card, try using status column value from SharePoint integration object or using ThisItem.columnName syntax